# Split String and keep null value

Tags: java, string, split

I want the split a string but also keep the null value. For example, I have a string like this:

```
String x = "x,y";
String result[] = y.split(",");
// then i will get result like this:
//result[] = ["x","y"]
```

But if I have a string like this:

```
String y = "x,";
String result[]=y.split(",");
//i will get something thing like this:
//result[] = ["x"]
```

I want the keep the null value as well. Is it possible for me to get a result like this: `result[]=["x",""]` using the `split` method?

Comment: use `x.split (",", -1)`

Comment: also add some semicolons to your code, and split `y` not `x`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) for the *two-argument* `split`:

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) for the one-argument `split` says:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

The last two sentences of the 2-argument javadoc imply that negative values of `limit` have the same behavior as a zero value (which is the same behavior as the one-argument `split`) except for the trailing empty strings.  So if you want to keep the trailing empty strings, any negative value for the limit will work.  Thus:

```
String result[] = y.split(",", -1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works!